# I need help making a terminal command on my M1 Mac Mini to restart my minecraft server if it crashes

Tags: java, macos, server, automation, minecraft

I have been looking for a long time to see if anyone has had an answer to my issue, but it doesn't seem to exist. I recently found I rarely used M1 Mac Mini. Since I had barely used it, I decided to turn it into a functioning server that runs 24/7. The only issue is that sometimes while I'm sleeping and my friends are playing, the server crashes, and there's no way of starting it back up unless I'm awake. So I'm looking for help on how to make a .command file that either A.) It Pings the server every minute, and if it senses it's down, it terminates the current terminal and restarts the start command. B.) Once the server crashes and the terminal ends, it restarts. I prefer to go with option A, but I'll take any help that I get! Thank you so much in advance, everyone!

I tried a script online, and one of them goes like this.

```
while true
do
cd Desktop
cd server
/Library/Internet_Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/java -Xmx7G -Xms7G -jar forgeserver.jar

echo "If you want to completely stop the server process now, press Ctrl+C before
the time is up!"
echo "Rebooting in:"
for i in 5 4 3 2 1
echo "$i..."
sleep 1
done
echo "Rebooting now!"
done
```

However I am met with this error

```
Last login: Thu Feb  9 02:37:12 on ttys001
/Users/myname/Desktop/start.command ; exit;                                  
davidking@Davids-Mac-mini ~ % /Users/myname/Desktop/start.command ; exit;
/Users/davidking/Desktop/start.command: line 11: syntax error near unexpected token `echo'
'Users/davidking/Desktop/start.command: line 11: `echo "$i..."

Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.

[Process completed]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like that:

```
while true; do
  ping -c 1 -W 1 your_server_IP
  if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "Server is up"
  else
    echo "Server is down, restarting..."
    # Add your server restart command here
    /path/to/restart/command
  fi
  sleep 60
done
```

The `ping -c 1 -W 1 your_server_IP` command sends one Echo Request packet to `your_server_IP`, and waits for a response for 1 second. If a response is received, it means the server is up and running. If no response is received, it means the server is down.

You have to save this file as a `.command` file and add it to your PATH.

Let me know if it works or you're getting errors! I'll be happy to help :)